# How to make Firefox only suggest complete URLs, and not just the host?

Tags: firefox

I love the feature that Firefox searches my history and bookmarks when I start typing in the address bar.

However since recently, Firefox also suggests URLs of the form `<host>/` when I start typing parts of a host name, although I neither have visited nor bookmarked that exact URL. This is quite annoying because there are a lot of servers (especially company-internal ones) which don't respond on these URLs. Typically, they require a special port (and I have the right one in my history), but Firefox still tricks me into using the wrong, default port.

So, how can I disable the host completion feature and make Firefox only propose the exact URLs that I have visited or bookmarked?

**EDIT** to clarify the expected behaviour: When I start typing a host name in the address bar and hit enter, I want Firefox to open the first element of the history/bookmark search results shown *below* the address bar, and not the URL which consists just of the host name, which is shown *in* the address bar. Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just found out that the feature I am not quite happy with is the [inline auto-complete](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Inline_autocomplete) option of the location bar (which is one of [multiple auto-complete options](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Changing_autocomplete_behavior_-_Firefox)). Apparently, it is not possible to change the behaviour of inline auto-complete so that only full URLs from the history are proposed.

But it already helped me to disable the option (by setting `browser.urlbar.autoFill` to `false` on the about:config page). In this way, I still need to press down and enter to select the first matching history entry, but at least I am no longer tricked into trying to open URLs that will show an error page.

Answer (score 2):

As of 2019, the prospector extensions and the options mentioned by @oberlies are not available any more.

A solution was mentioned on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/a6sy1r/firefox_location_bar_autocomplete_suggest_most/eby0tds). If you got to *Library* and then *Bookmarks*, *Show all bookmarks* (alternatively press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd>), each bookmark has a keyword entry. By adding the short version of the website, Firefox will proceed directly to the bookmarked URL instead of the incomplete URL.

[image: See screenshot.]

You need a shortcut for each substring of the desired URL:

- e
- ex
- exa
- exam
- ...
- example.com

Answer (score 0):

There is an extension for this: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/prospector-speak-words/

It doesn't autocomplete the full url in the address bar like Crhome or Opera, but it highlights the first result from history, and hitting `enter` brings you the correct address.